# Tableau Server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

we are builing a big data solution on AWS. The processed data which is stored in Redshift needs to be exposed out through Tableau dashboards. I'd like to know the best practices for implementing this kind of a solution.

Assuming the data tonnage of 5GB/day and 10 users trying to access the dashboards... Which one would be an optimal option to go with(considering the cost and flexibility)
-Deploying the tableau server on AWS and connecting to Redshift (within the cluster)
-Deploying the tableau server outside the AWS and connect it to the Redshift on AWS

Any help/ suggestions on this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By maintaining all the servers on AWS you will have faster data transfer, less data transfer charges, secure and contained data transfer within your VPC, and you won't have to expose the Redshift cluster to the internet. So the advantages would be added security and data transfer speed and cost.

Otherwise, there are no real technical hurdles you would encounter going with one solution versus the other.